# loaded picture editing

Tags: c#, drawing, picturebox

I am supposed to load an image from a file and this image should cover 80% of pictureBox and then draw something on it... With loading there is no problem, but trying to draw anything on it drops an error that has an unproper parameter (g.FillRectangle...).

I found on stack advice to refresh pictureBox, but it changes nothing...
And i have no idea how to solve this...

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Width = (int)(Width * 0.80);
    pictureBox1.Height = (int)(Height * 0.80);

    // open file dialog 
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    // image filters
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // display image in picture box
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        // image file path
        //  textBox1.Text = open.FileName;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 20, 50);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not draw on the Bitmap image before loading it to Picture box?

Comment: Where does the variable `g` come from? I assume it's meant to represent a `Graphics` instance?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Graphics.FromImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) or [`Control.CreateGraphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods for draw on your image:

```
var img = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
{
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 20, 50);  
}
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

or draw directly on `PictureBox` by `Paint` event (for example by using [`Anonymous Methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)):

```
pictureBox1.Paint += (s, e) => e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 20, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code working fine for me.... Can you try the same

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Width = (int)(Width * 0.80);
            pictureBox1.Height = (int)(Height * 0.80);


            // open file dialog 
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

            // image filters
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // display image in picture box
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                // image file path
                //  textBox1.Text = open.FileName;
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 20, 50);
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi all! 
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
This works! I dont know why my implementation of Graphic g didnt work, it was implemented straight on the beginning of whole programm....